# Getting array name of search data in type ahead js

Tags: javascript, typeahead

```
$('#search_restaurant').typeahead({
minLength: 1,
order: "asc",
 template: "{{display}} <small style='color:#999;' id={{group}}>{{group}} </small>",
source: {
Restaurant: {
    url: ["sqlfiles/search_data.php", "data.country"]
},
Estb: {
    url: ["sqlfiles/search_data.php", "data.dish"]
},
Sub: {
    url: ["sqlfiles/search_data.php", "data.sub"]
},
Cusines: {
    url: [
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "sqlfiles/search_data.php",
            data: {myKey: "myValue"}
        },
        "data.capital"
    ]
}
},

});
```

I am using running coder type ahead js here i am getting the data but what i want is the name of array of the selected data like Restaurant,Estb,Sub,Cusines in a java script variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
callback: {
    onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {
        // item.group should be what you are looking for
        console.log(item)
    }
}
});
```

that's the solution